# Are wipefs -af and mdadm --zero-superblock equivalent for erasing raid metadata?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I saw instructions about how to remove software raid, and some of them contain both instructions: `wipefs -af <device>` and `mdadm --zero-superblock --force <device>`.

Is it neccesary to use both? How do they differ in result?

Here I have raid made of /dev/sda3 and /dev/sdb3. I have made a small test, and it looks like result is the same.

```
machine1:~# wipefs /dev/sda3  # <-- see the signature on sda3
offset               type
----------------------------------------------------------------
0x1000               linux_raid_member   [raid]
                     LABEL: machine1:md_system
                     UUID:  54f255a8-c32d-2a67-f728-151f89a7471b

machine1:~# wipefs -af /dev/sda3  # <-- wipe signature using wipefs
/dev/sda3: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x00001000 (linux_raid_member): fc 4e 2b a9
machine1:~# wipefs /dev/sda3  # <-- as you can see, signature was erased
machine1:~# 
machine1:~# wipefs /dev/sdb3  # <-- see signature on sdb3
offset               type
----------------------------------------------------------------
0x1000               linux_raid_member   [raid]
                     LABEL: machine1:md_system
                     UUID:  54f255a8-c32d-2a67-f728-151f89a7471b

machine1:~# mdadm --misc --zero-superblock --force /dev/sdb3  # <-- wipe signature using mdadm
machine1:~# wipefs /dev/sdb3  # <-- as you can see, signature was also erased
machine1:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

Both instructions lead to **zero-ing** the **superblock**, that means deleting the **signature** of the filesystem which is here the **metadata** about the **RAID**.

Comment: So, can I skip the `mdadm --zero-superblock` when I will call a `wipefs --all` after that?

Comment: Yes same here :)